# IOS In App Purchase Receipt AppleInc Root CA Verification

Tags: ios, ssl, openssl, in-app-purchase

I'm currently attempting to implement a form of local receipt validation as detailed on [apple's developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW18):

I'm running into a snag however.  I believe the certs within the receipt are not validating against apples root CA correctly.

> 87937:error:04077068:rsa routines:RSA_verify:bad signature:rsa_sign.c:263:
> 87937:error:0D0C5006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:EVP lib:a_verify.c:179:
> 87937:error:21075075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify   error:pk7_smime.c:244:Verify error:certificate signature failure

running gdb shows the failure is happening here:

> (gdb) bt
>
> #0  RSA_verify (dtype=64, m=0xbfffe1b4 "", m_len=20, sigbuf=0x37af90 "", siglen=256, rsa=0x37ca80) at rsa_sign.c:263
>
> #1  0x0013e6fa in EVP_VerifyFinal (ctx=0xbfffe2b0, sigbuf=0x37af90 "", siglen=256, pkey=0x37ca60) at p_verify.c:107
>
> #2  0x00152b38 in ASN1_item_verify (it=0x20b118, a=0x37a5b0, signature=0x37a5c0, asn=0x37a460, pkey=0x37ca60) at a_verify.c:176
>
> #3  0x0018e73c in X509_verify (a=0x37a400, r=0x37ca60) at x_all.c:76
>
> #4  0x001866ef in internal_verify (ctx=0xbffff5a8) at x509_vfy.c:998
>
> #5  0x00185ad9 in X509_verify_cert (ctx=0xbffff5a8) at x509_vfy.c:305
>
> #6  0x001b4f1d in PKCS7_verify (p7=0x3792c0, certs=0x0, store=0x379160, indata=0x0, out=0x379260, flags=0) at pk7_smime.c:240
>
> #7  0x00001dd6 in main () at pkcs7_decrypt.c:42
> Current language:  auto; currently minimal
> (gdb)

It's failing to verify the root CA's pub key against the intermediate cert "/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations/CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority".

Running openssl verify against the the intermediate cert directly yields a similar result, though I may not be doing this correctly:

> bbooth@Bills-MacBook-Air:forge$ openssl verify -verbose -CAfile apple.pem devrel.pem
>
> devrel.pem: /C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations/CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
>
> error 7 at 0 depth lookup:certificate signature failure
>
> 88161:error:04077068:rsa routines:RSA_verify:bad signature:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.2/src/crypto/rsa/rsa_sign.c:263:
>
> 88161:error:0D0C5006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:EVP lib:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.2/src/crypto/asn1/a_verify.c:179:
>
> bbooth@Bills-MacBook-Air:forge$

Here's the code I'm running in OSX:

```
fp = fopen("AppleIncRootCertificate.cer", "rb");
fread(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, fp);
b_x509 = BIO_new_mem_buf(buf, 1215);

Apple = d2i_X509_bio(b_x509, NULL);
fclose(fp);

X509_STORE *store = X509_STORE_new();
X509_STORE_add_cert(store, Apple);

bio = BIO_new_file("receipt.cer", "r");
p7 = d2i_PKCS7_bio(bio, NULL);
BIO_free(bio);

ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
bio = BIO_new_file("receipt.dec", "w");
PKCS7_verify(p7, NULL, store, NULL, bio, 0);
```

Feel free to look at [the receipt](https://github.com/wrbooth/bingist/raw/master/iapval/receipt.cer).
I must admit, I'm a novice to pretty much all of the systems this problem touches on, any and all advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was simple, that receipt was corrupted somehow (despite being able to parse it.)  Sending this receipt to the appstore receipt verifier yields a receipt data format error.

I retried the code on a receipt that validates on apple servers without error, and it works fine.